# If $|x+2|<2$ show that $|3x-2|<14$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

If $|x+2|<2$ show that $|3x-2|<14$

solution so far:

$|x+2|<2 \Leftrightarrow -2<x+2<2 \Leftrightarrow -4<x<0 \Leftrightarrow -12<3x<0 \Leftrightarrow -14<3x-2<-2$

This approach doesn't seem to be very helpful. Any thoughts of how to prove this?

Comment: When working with inequalities with absolute values in mind, it is helpful to remember that $-x<a<x\Rightarrow|a|<x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are one step away from the solution. You have
$$-14\lt3x-2\lt-2$$
Thus,
$$|3x-2|\lt\max(|-14|,|-2|)$$
$$|3x-2|\lt14$$

Answer (score 0):

$-14<3x-2<-2 \iff -14<3x-2<-2<14 \implies -14 < 3x-2 <14 \iff |3x-2| < 14 $